# React native Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices')

Tags: android, react-native, webrtc

I am trying to connect react native webrtc lib to my react native project. I can go to screen normally, but when I press button to start the call I receive following error:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices')]
```

This was tested on both android emulator and android phone. Both had same issue.

```
   const startLocalStream = async () => {
        // isFront will determine if the initial camera should face user or environment
        const isFront = true;
          let devices = await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();  //this is where I get error 
          console.log(devices); 
    
    
        const facing = isFront ? 'front' : 'environment';
        const videoSourceId = devices.find(device => device.kind === 'videoinput' && device.facing === facing);
        const facingMode = isFront ? 'user' : 'environment';
        const constraints = {
          audio: true,
          video: {
            mandatory: {
              minWidth: 500, // Provide your own width, height and frame rate here
              minHeight: 300,
              minFrameRate: 30,
            },
            facingMode,
            optional: videoSourceId ? [{ sourceId: videoSourceId }] : [],
          },
        };
        const newStream = await mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
        setLocalStream(newStream);
      };
    
      const startCall = async id => {
        const localPC = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);
        localPC.addStream(localStream);
    
        const roomRef = await db.collection('rooms').doc(id);
        const callerCandidatesCollection = roomRef.collection('callerCandidates');
        localPC.onicecandidate = e => {
          if (!e.candidate) {
            console.log('Got final candidate!');
            return;
          }
          callerCandidatesCollection.add(e.candidate.toJSON());
        };
    
        localPC.onaddstream = e => {
          if (e.stream && remoteStream !== e.stream) {
            console.log('RemotePC received the stream call', e.stream);
            setRemoteStream(e.stream);
          }
        };
    
        const offer = await localPC.createOffer();
        await localPC.setLocalDescription(offer);
    
        const roomWithOffer = { offer };
        await roomRef.set(roomWithOffer);
    
        roomRef.onSnapshot(async snapshot => {
          const data = snapshot.data();
          if (!localPC.currentRemoteDescription && data.answer) {
            const rtcSessionDescription = new RTCSessionDescription(data.answer);
            await localPC.setRemoteDescription(rtcSessionDescription);
          }
        });
    
        roomRef.collection('calleeCandidates').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
          snapshot.docChanges().forEach(async change => {
            if (change.type === 'added') {
              let data = change.doc.data();
              await localPC.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(data));
            }
          });
        });
    
        setCachedLocalPC(localPC);
      };
```

How to fix it? I am using official lib for react native webrtc.

Comment: Are you serving the page over an HTTPS connection?

Comment: @giavac currently it is running with expo offline so HTTP

Comment: I would try with HTTPS, as this may be a permissions issue.

Comment: Do you know how to try it with HTTPS please?